# How to access nested list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, nested

Say I have a `List<B>` which is a property of `A`.

Now I'm trying to access `List<B> from List<A>`.

```
Class A
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
}

Class B
{
    List<A> a;
    int ID;
    string Name;
}

Class ViewModel
{
    List<B> b;
}

Class Main
{
    ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();
    //I want to set _model.b.a to List<A> variable
}
```

Is there any way I can use this?

Comment: #1) Your premise is not correct. You do not have a List<B> which is a property of A. You have a List<A> which is a property of B. #2) List<B> is a list of instances of B objects. That means that _model.b.a is not valid, because _model.b is a list -> it is not an instance of b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_model.b` is a list, so if you want to set the value of `a` for every item in the list, you could do this:

```
Class Main
{
    var yourValues = new List<A>();
    ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();
    foreach (var item in _model.b)
    {
       item.a = yourValues;
    }
}
```

You could also use ForEach to do the loop:

```
model.b.ForEach(i => i.a = yourValues);
```

Comment: Well, to tell you frankly, I had thought about this too. But isn't there any single liner approach instead of going through a loop?

Comment: or you could give each item.a a new List<A>, i.e. item.a = new List<A>(); inside the foreach loop

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar I updated my answer to use `ForEach`, but the same operation is being performed.

Comment: @Spock I was only using `yourValues` as a placeholder, I'm assuming he has actual data to set the lists to.

Comment: Awesome thanks man. This is what I was asking for. Yes I have a List<A> from DB. So for each List<A> in B under List<B> i want to set that List<A>

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is as such:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6knni1

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();
        var AllOfMyAs = _model.Bs.SelectMany(sm => sm.As).ToList(); // Here's the "main event"

        Console.WriteLine(AllOfMyAs.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (A a in AllOfMyAs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
        }
    }

}

public class A
{
    public int ID {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<A> As { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        As = new List<A>();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Bs = new List<B>()
        {
            new B()
            {
                As = new List<A>()
                {
                    new A()
                    {
                        Name = "test1"
                    },
                    new A()
                    {
                        Name = "test2"
                    }
                }               
            },
            new B()
            {
                As = new List<A>()
                {
                    new A()
                    {
                        Name = "another B"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Based on comments https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8g2Du :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();

        _model.Bs.ForEach(fe => fe.As = PlaceHolderAsData());

    }

    public static List<A> PlaceHolderAsData()
    {
        return new List<A>()
        {
            new A()
            {
                Name = "blah blah"
            },
            new A()
            {
                Name = "Bob Loblaw"
            }
        };
    }

}

public class A
{
    public int ID {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<A> As { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        As = new List<A>();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Bs = new List<B>()
        {
            new B()
            {
                As = new List<A>()
            },
            new B()
            {
                As = new List<A>()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is what I achieved already. But it's Get right? I want to Set all the A's of B's.

Comment: Wait so you want each list of A in each B to be the same list of A?   What purpose does that serve?  I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: I'm not sure if this is more what you're asking about, but take a look:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8g2Du

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Yes this is what I was asking for. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comment I wrote above suggests, your premise is somewhat convoluted, so the question is hard to answer, because I am not sure what you are really intending.

If it is indeed working with lists, as you say...

What you are asking to do is something like this:

```
// create the list of B objects...
_model.b = new List<B>();

// add one B object to the list...
_model.b.Add(new B());

// set the first (and only) B object in the list's a property to a new list of A objects
_model.b[0].a = new List<A>();

// optionally add an A object to the List<A> property
_model.b[0].a.Add(new A());
```

But I think what you want is something very different:

```
public Class A
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}

public Class B : A
{
    public List<A> a = new List<A>();
}

Class ViewModel
{
    public List<B> b = new List<B>();
}

Class Main
{
    ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();
    //I want to set _model.b.a to List<A> variable

    ==> not sure what you want here ==> there is no _model.b.a since b is a list of A objects not an instance of B itself.
}
```

Comment: Well I wanted to achieve what was suggested above I wanted to achieve `model.b.ForEach(i => i.a = MyList<A>);` Where MyList<A> will be populated from DB.